# Is it better to check existence of an element before removing it?

Tags: jquery

My page has an alert box that shows when there are no entries to show. When a new entry is added via AJAX I remove this element with a simple:

```
$('#empty-alert').remove();
```

I was thinking: When I add following entries I simply call this method again regardless the element exists or not. Is it better to check the existence first and if it exists, call `remove()`? Like:

```
if($('#empty-alert').length){
    $('#empty-alert').remove();
}
```

Or is this just extra work when the element does exist and the first idea is already checking existence and removing in one call?

Comment: If you were going to do the second option, then you should put the result of `$('#empty-alert')` into a variable and then use that to check the length and remove.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For reference, in fairly loose terms from my understanding:

The `$()` selector in jQuery always returns a jQuery collection. if there is no matching element the collection is empty.

When you call a function such as `remove()` on a jQuery collection it actually iterates through the collection perform the action on each element in it. If the collection is empty it will never iterate, thus never call the `remove()` on any element in this case.

For example, using this case:

`$('#empty-alert')` will either return a collection of `["#empty-alert jQuery object"]` or `[]` (empty array);

calling .remove() is effectively doing something like this behind the scenes:

```
//jqCollection is one of the arrays previously mentioned

jqCollection.each(function(){
    this.remove(); //'this' is a single jQuery object from the jqcollection
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and bonus point for the behind the scenes look :) Sounds like the extra check would indeed - as I thought - fire an unnecessary lookup of existence.

Answer (score 2):

> Or is this just extra work when the element does exist and the first idea is already checking existence and removing in one call?

Calling remove() on non existing element gives no error, so you can use it with not element existance check.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/knFK4/1/ there's no need to previously check the element existence when you remove it. No error will be raised if the element is missing

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs http://api.jquery.com/remove/ If you need to do this check they will tell you about that.

Comment: Thanks but I don't wanted to know if I *need* to check, more if it is usefull or just extra work.