# jQuery check before delete tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

Does it make sense to check for existing tag before doing something with it? Or is jQuery doing thing on the fly?

Here a samplecode

```
$('#my_ul li.active').removeClass('active');
```

or...

```
if(  $('#my_ul li.active').length ) {
    $('#my_ul li.active').removeClass('active');
}
```

Comment: A very simple way to find out would be to run your first line of code on a page where there's no matching element, and see if you get an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it better to check existence of an element before removing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897633/is-it-better-to-check-existence-of-an-element-before-removing-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery does a loop for every element returned by the selection. So if you have zero elements in an array then the looping occurs zero times. take this example

html

```
<ul>
   <li>Hello World</li>
</ul>
```

the JavaScript is

```
var $('li');
```

that will return an array of elements if you console log it it will look like this;

```
[<li>Hello world</li>]
```

since the above is an array when jQuery loops through it will do it once.
However if the section returns zero items the loop will never occur there

```
$('div').removeClass(".myClass");
```

basically the removeClass plugin (it is a plugin by the way its just a plugin thats part of the core jQuery code)

the plugin will do something like this;

```
$.each($('div), function () {
  //some code to remove the class 
})
```

Hope this helps you understand the internals of jQuery

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't make sense. It's neither faster nor useful. Don't do it.

Simply do

```
 $('#my_ul li').removeClass('active');
```

and there won't be any error, even if there is no such element, and even if the `li` elements don't have the `active` class.

Comment: You were 1 sec faster! +1 to you